# Ocean API: A debugger has been found running in your system. Please, unload it from memory and restart your program

Tags: visual-studio, ocean, petrel

I wrote a simple code in Ocean API. When i want to start it without debugging it works and i can see  the plugin in Petrel. However when i try to debug it a message appears:

cEngineer.dll **A debugger has been found running in your system.Please, unload it from memory and restart your program.**
[Error- Debugging Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp1NR.png)

How can i solve this issue?

Many Thanks,

Comment: You probably only got a Petrel runtime license.  You need a developer license, contact Schlumberger for details.

Comment: @HansPassant, while you are technically correct, the Ocean SDK license does not affect the ability to attach a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Petrel cannot be started in Debug mode. You can attach the debugger to it after it is launched. One trick to get the debugger attached early in your plug-in code is to place: 
Debugger.Launch(); 
in your IModule.Initialize method.

Comment: Then you're attaching to the wrong code-type. Select "Managed" instead.

Comment: @RJFalconer I have opened a Petrel Project and then I try to attach the managed type. When I attach it, the VS changed to Debug mode and the Petrel project was hide! however it was available in the Process tab of Task Manager. I don't know what is the next step!

Comment: @user7047425 In regard to the use of Debugger.Launch() in Initialize method , I got the same error while it must pop up a window and let me to choose the appropriate debugger !!!

Answer (score 1):

The 64-bit version of Petrel is hardened against reverse engineering during initialization, but the previous answer is correct:  attaching later (e.g. with Debugger.Launch(), or manually after the UI has appeared) works fine.

Alternatively, you can use the developer-only 32-bit build of Petrel (check the Ocean developer site).  Pure .NET-based plugins will work fine, and it can be launched directly in the VS debugger.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried these solutions before. unfortunately, they did not work and the mentioned error remains yet.I got the same error when I add the debugger to Module.Initialize method. I also tried to attach Petrel when its UI is appeared. Petrel is available in the process list, but I can not select it to attach. it should be noted that the type of petrel process is "IntelliTrace Debug Engine"!  I use Petrel and ocean 2014.